# Jenkins failing to clone Bitbucket links during Rspec Puppet unit tests

Tags: jenkins, github, ssh, rspec, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins build to clone a Bitbucket link and run unit tests I've written against some Puppet modules. I've got Jenkins set up with an SSH keypair and have verified that it can clone the Bitbucket repository initially, but when the unit tests run and clone separate modules as part of the test, I get an error that the public key does not work.

```
     Permission denied (publickey).
     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
     and the repository exists.
```

I've verified that the build is running under the Jenkins user and that the keys are in the .ssh directory, what else can I try to fix it?

Comment: I was able to fix it by logging into the Jenkins Docker instance and using the SSH keypair from there instead of the one on the Jenkins server hosting the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by logging into the Jenkins Docker instance and using the SSH keypair from there instead of the one on the Jenkins server hosting the instance. It worked completely after I did this.